# Run multiple script python in Bash script in same time

Tags: python, bash, process, background, sigkill

so here is my test.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

python test.py & 
test_PID=$!
python test2.py & 
test2_PID=$!
python test3.py & 
test3_PID=$!

sleep 10


kill -15 $test_PID
kill -15 $test2_PID
kill -15 $test3_PID
```

so the three python scripts writes in three files data in the same time and after 10 seconds i kill them but sometimes i don't find data in text files and sometimes and just find data in one of the three files,
Without the kill instruction below ,it writes fine to the three files but never stops and with the kill it stops after 10s but don't write in files.
How to kill it after 10 seconds and still the script python does its job by writing into the file ?

Comment: You might want to post the scripts too so we can see how you're writing data to the files.

Comment: Maybe the scripts take longer than 10s to execute?

Comment: Yes,Thanks that was the problem,it took more than 10s to execute :D